# Installing missing dependencies

Tags: pantheon-files, pantheon, release-odin, dependencies

So one of the first things I tried to do with my fresh install of Elementary OS turned out to be a noob mistake. I followed a youtube tutorial to install Elementary Tweaks only to learn that it's not compatible with Odin. I should have installed Pantheon Tweaks instead.

So I follow the instructions to do that and it says missing dependencies. "libgranite5" and "libpantheon-files-core0" to be exact. But when I try to "sudo apt-get install" those they return "E: Unable to locate package". So now I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

I can help you with the `elementary-tweaks` issue, it won't work on Odin/Jólnir, you'll have to install `pantheon-tweaks`. Here you can find how to install it: `https://github.com/pantheon-tweaks/pantheon-tweaks`

Comment: I tried that. it returns: `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 elementary-tweaks : Depends: libgranite5 (>= 0.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
 pantheon-files : Depends: libpantheon-files-core0 (= 6.1.1+r5124+pkg110~ubuntu6.1) but 6.1.0+r5055+pkg107~ubuntu6.1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).`

Comment: Try `sudo apt purge elementary-tweaks`

Comment: ^ purge did not work. `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 pantheon-files : Depends: libpantheon-files-core0 (= 6.1.1+r5124+pkg110~ubuntu6.1) but 6.1.0+r5055+pkg107~ubuntu6.1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).`

Comment: It seems that you have an issue with the `pantheon-files`. Try to purge and reinstall that package. For some reason, you're not getting the latest version, which currently is `6.1.1+r5124+pkg110~ubuntu6.1`.

Also check your repositories and remove and `daily` versions.

Comment: guess what? I can't purge pantheon-files because of the missing libgranite5 dependencies! It's like a chicken and egg problem. At this point I'm considering a fresh reinstall.

Comment: Looks you need to get a later version of pantheon-tweaks - version 1.0.3 appears to be the latest.  Odin 6.1 uses libgranite6, not libgranite5.  There was an issue with the latest update of Files meaning you might need to reboot before it will update.

Comment: Then purge libgranite5, in short, try to purge anything that doesn't belong to Odin.